# What confidence level and margin of error are implicit in the statement the probabilistic predictions of quantum mechanics have been firmly confirmed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, epr-experiment

This can be formulated as a problem of hypothesis testing,  or sampling,  in a statistical framework.  For a confidence level of 0.95,  and an error not exceeding 0.005,  you would need a sample size of about 40000. For example, for a parametric down conversion (PDC) source of entangled photons,  with an efficiency of a few entangled pairs per minute,  you would need almost a month of continuous operation, in order to collect the required amount of data  (that can be analyzed later,  based on coincidence timing of detection ). If quantum mechanics is only an approximation of a deeper,  nonlinear hidden variable theory,  the deviations could involve even smaller margins of error (thus requiring larger samples ).  Have these types of experiments  actually been performed,  in order to detect any possible deviations from the probabilistic predictions of quantum mechanics?

Comment: It sounds as though your asking for a reference request - your ideal answer would include a citation of a paper summarizing such experiments / statistical appraisal of experiments, no? Also, please expand all acronyms - I assume PDC is "parametric downconversion"?

Comment: Yes,  by PDC I mean parametric down conversion.  I do not doubt the statistical accuracy of EPR experiments that confirm the violation of Bell's inequalities,  for example,  but I suspect subtle deviations from the probabilistic predictions of quantum mechanics,  if the sample size is sufficiently large. I think that these experiments did not go far enough,  where surprises might appear.

Comment: Basically,  I suspect that quantum theory is a linear approximation of a deeper,  nonlinear,  underlying reality, and I want to know whether experiments in this direction have been performed, with attention to statistical detail .

Comment: If the point of the statistical model is to model the hidden variables and approximate their effect, then why would there be any *systematic* deviation?

Comment: Nonlinearity is highly counterintuitive.  With a linear model,  you can probably answer Buffon needle type of problems on a strange attractor,  but just as an example,  you could not even use the Lebesgue measure on its Poincare section  (of the strange attractor ),  which is a Cantor dust set.  You would need the Hausdorff measure on Cantor sets.  As a consequence,  those averages  (Lebesgue integrals ) that appear  in the proof of Bell's theorem would not exist (as s bonus,  due to sensitivity to initial conditions,  those functions  are far from continuous,  or even integrable ).

Comment: In other words,  nonlinearity is a game changer.  The question is how subtle are those deviations,  and whether they are in the experimental range.  To address your comment,  any linear models of nonlinear phenomena are far from perfect.

Comment: There are a lot of people here interested in establishing hidden variable theories! I think kpv did a statistical analysis a while back about this.

Comment: Who says that there is a single such number? There's been a wide array of different experiments, with different degrees of safeguards against the various so-called 'loopholes', and there is a trade-off between how much you mitigate those features and how much data you can acquire. An overarching meta-analysis trying to aggregate those results into a single number would not be appropriate - you can't separate the physics from the statistics here. You'll likely have to look up each individual paper for the numbers, though there's probably good reviews to point at them.

Comment: I am not aware of an experiment where  they  say "well,  quantum mechanics predicts that the probability of this event is p , and our  extremely large experimental data set  (million point data set, for example  ) tells us with high confidence level that is a correct prediction  (within a very small margin of error )".  The more interesting situation is when the experimenter reaches a different conclusion,  like "based on our experimental evidence " , most likely there is a small deviation from the prediction of quantum mechanics, p'.  That would be interesting,  wouldn't it?

Comment: Since I am a mathematician,  not a physicist,  and I am not familiar with the experimental state of the art in this direction,  I would like to know if these types of experiments have ever been performed,  or considered. That is the essence of my question.

Comment: Although I cannot answer your question directly, you might use this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491689902765 as a starting point.

Comment: I did look up some of the papers dealing with this issue.  None of them (those that I had access to ) had a sufficiently large data set,  in order to be rigorously,  statistically significant , and avoid the small sample size problem.  Surely,  I did not read them all,  so a state of the art reference would be nice.

Comment: And you cannot combine them. We are talking about repeated identical trials,  not repeated groups of different trials.  The systems must be prepared and measured in the same way, and subjected to identical experimental conditions.

Comment: Thank you @EmilioPisanty for your feedback.  I did not raise the loophole issue at all. I am convinced that larger experimental data sets will show the same strong violations of Bell's inequalities.  But the same larger data sets might also show slight deviations from the probabilistic predictions of quantum mechanics.  I strongly believe that the act of measurement in quantum mechanics has a strong nonlinear character,  and this nonlinearity is the real source of the fallacious phenomenon  (my opinion ) of quantum nonlocality,  or what Einstein called ""spooky action at a distance ".

Comment: So there are two different issues here  (connected, but different ).  First,  larger experimental data sets could show slight deviations from the probabilistic predictions of quantum mechanics.  Second,  local realism is perfectly compatible with experimental evidence,  if we we consider nonlinear models for the act of measurement, in quantum mechanics .  That is true even if there will be strong violations of  Bell's inequalities  (I explained why in one of the comments above,  basically Bell's inequalities lose their validity as a restrictive requirement,  in nonlinear models ).

Comment: I'll repeat myself once, but I don't see the point in doing it again. You're trying to separate the physics from the statistics in a way that the physicists that implement and report the experiments don't consider appropriate. The larger data sets you're after simply don't exist, because the different experiments are carried out under different conditions and pretty much no one would consider it appropriate or useful to aggregate the data, which means that individual papers are the only sources you're likely to find.

Comment: If you think the sample sizes in the published literature are too small, then your best bet is to convince those groups to run larger-sample experiments, ideally by doing the scientific-method thing and publishing a detailed, specific prediction that provides actual meat to your claims that nonlinear models are consistent with local realism without being overpowered. (And, in that regard, you won't be alone; cf. e.g. §5 [here](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/npcomplete.pdf), where you see that even small nonlinearities will often make for wildly overpowered theories.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty   Basically,  we need a model governed by a nonlinear Schrodinger equation,  that is consistent with the predictions of the usual quantum mechanics  (so the no cloning and no FTL signaling theorems  are still valid,  but note that consistent doesn't necessarily mean identical predictions ), for which the wavefunction collapses by the act of amplification.  There is no need to invoke the spooky action at a distance  (in order to explain Aspect type experiments ),  because the proof of Bell's theorem collapses within a nonlinear framework  (as explained in a comment above ).

Comment: So local realism is preserved.  Well,  there are at least two models that could satisfy these requirements, the pilot wave Bohmian mechanics,  and GRW (specially GRW ). Such  a theory would be consistent with the usual  (linear ) quantum mechanics,  but there might be small deviations in its probabilistic predictions.  That's where the larger experimental data sets would make a difference.  A statistical confirmation that these deviations exist would also be a confirmation that the nonlinear effects are real.